Functional equation of real analytic Eisenstein series
Define $$E(z,s)=\sum_{\gamma\in\Gamma_\infty \setminus \Gamma} Im(\gamma z)^s=\dfrac{1}{2}\sum_{(c,d)=1} \dfrac{y^s}{|cz+d|^{2s}}.$$
I did several calculations in the same way of one does to get the functional equation of $\zeta(s)$ and I got the following functional equation: $$E(z,1-s)=\dfrac{\pi^{-2s+1}\Gamma(s)\zeta(2s)E(z,s)}{\Gamma(1-s)\zeta(2-2s)}.$$ I have two questions:
1- Is it correct? I didn't find this anywhere, so I couldn't check.
2- How can I simplify this expression? I want to obtain the analytical continuation of the $E(z,s)$, but I can't see it with this expression. I tried to apply the Legendre's duplication formula and Euler’s reflection formula as in link, but apparently it does not work.
I appreciate your help, thank you in advance.

In this MO-post the functional equation $E(z,s)=E(z,1-s)$ is proved. They put the factors into the definition of $E(z,s)$.

1- To make sense with Zagier's article, it should be $2\Gamma(s)\pi^{-s}\zeta(2s)E(z,s)$. I am confused about that.
2- After the equality $$\Gamma(s)\pi^{-s}\zeta(2s)E(z,s)=\dfrac{1}{s-1}-\dfrac{1}{s}+\int_1^\infty (\Theta_z(t)-1)(t^{s-1}+t^{-s})dt,$$ he says "which proves the functional equation". I didn't get it. Could you explain it? Sorry

What is the functional equation?

Also I did not get the equality between the $\int_0^\infty$ integral and the right-hand side. I did the math and couldn't get it.

For 2-, you can see that the RHS is invariant under the change of variables $s \mapsto 1 - s$, which shows that the LHS must also be invariant under this change of variables.

Yes, it is correct. That expression can be found in link. Apparently a simplification is not needed, since the author didn't do it.
